# Python Subir Imagen a Firebase

Tags: python, firebase

Intento desde Python subir una imagen a firebase con cualquier librería o pyrebase hasta el momento he podido solo enviar datos y necesito subir una imagen pero no logro poder hacerlo

```
import pyrebase

#Credenciales para la comunicación
config = {
    "apiKey": "AIzaSyDLepJDWNjxU869ZyFsCWmrmnjWsWcI7zE",
    "authDomain": "tutoriales-16b27.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://tutoriales-16b27.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "tutoriales-16b27.appspot.com"
}

#Inicializa la base de datos

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

data = {"Titulo de la variable1": "Dato1"}
db.child("Prueba").push(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este codigo sube una imagen a Storage

```
 import pyrebase

#Credenciales para la comunicación
config = {
    "apiKey": "AIzaSyDLepJDWNjxU869ZyFsCWmrmnjWsWcI7zE",
    "authDomain": "tutoriales-16b27.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://tutoriales-16b27.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "tutoriales-16b27.appspot.com"
}

#Inicializa la base de datos

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

#Subir una imagen a Storage
storage = firebase.storage()
storage.child("images/foto.jpg").put("imagen.jpg")
```